# trabajar con clases en PHP

Tags: php, clase

tengo una pequeña duda sobre como trabajar con clases en PHP si yo tengo un formulario llamado solicitud.php y tengo otro documento llamado clases.php en el cual tengo todas mis clases.

pero no se  como realizar el llamado de mi archivo solicitud.php a la clase que tengo en mi otro archivo.

**solicitud.php**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continuar</button>
        <?php $object = new GuardarProceso.User;
        print_r($object);?>
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="entradasalida" value="entradasalida" /> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**clases.php**:

```
class User{
    public $name, $password;
    function save_user(){
        echo "Save User code goes here";
    }
}
```

Comment: para llamar un archivo php dentro de otro archivo php tienes opciones como require, require_once, include e include_once

Comment: pero yo requiero hacer el llamado a la clase dentro de ese archivo, no se si se pueda como se usa en C#

Comment: si haces lo que te digo podrás llamar a la clase que ocupas

Comment: ¿Por qué pusiste GuardarProceso? con lo que tienes yo lo invocaría $object = new User(); para instanciar y luego $object->save_user(); para el método

Comment: Yo te recomiendo utilizar API's, [aquí](https://www.imaginanet.com/blog/servidor-rest-con-php-y-peticiones-mediante-jquery-y-ajax.html) un ejemplo de como crearlas. De esta manera con una petición AJAX obtenes los resultados arrojados de la API. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

**clase.php**

```
class User{
   public function save_user(){
   echo "hola mundo";
   }
}
```

**solicitud.php**

```
<?php
include('clase.php');
$user = new User;
$variable = $user->save_user();
?>
```